# Why do I get error Missing implementation?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm getting an error:

> [DCC Error] Test.pas(10): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method ICoTest64.MyFunc

Below is a snippet from the TLB file.

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: ICoTest64
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {76CF78FE-22A3-4C0B-B1A9-97634A453AE3}
// *********************************************************************//
  ICoTest64 = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{76CF78FE-22A3-4C0B-B1A9-97634A453AE3}']
    function MyFunc(const Range: System.OleVariant): System.OleVariant; safecall;
  end;
```

And here is the implementation

```
unit Test;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, ComObj, ComServ, ActiveX, Variants, Office2000, Excel2000, 
  adxAddIn, Test64_TLB,
  System.Classes, adxHostAppEvents, Dialogs, StdVcl;

type
  TCoTest64 = class(TadxAddin, ICoTest64)
  protected
    function MyFunc(var Range: System.OleVariant): System.OleVariant; safecall;
  end;

implementation

function TCoTest64.MyFunc(var Range: System.OleVariant): System.OleVariant;
begin
  Result:= 10;
end;

end.
```

As far as I can tell `implementation = interface`

I'm using Delphi XE2

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function parameter lists for `MyFunc` do not match. The declaration in the interface `ICoTest64` uses a `const` parameter. But your implementation in the class `TCoReporting64` uses a `var` parameter.

Assuming that the interface declaration is correct, you need to change your code thus:

```
type
  TCoReporting64 = class(TadxAddin, ICoTest64)
  protected
    function MyFunc(const Range: System.OleVariant): System.OleVariant; safecall;
  end;
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, It compiles now. I guess I was suffering from some form of blindness; it's just that almost all of the code is autogenerated by Delphi. So I did not notice the difference between the `const` and `var` declarations.